# Can I filter out or rename topics from a bag file?

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with several topics (a lot of them, actually), and I'm trying to launch it from a launch file.

However, in my test case that I want to run, I want to exclude a topic and insert my module to publish it instead. I was looking into either renaming the culprit topic, or just filter out a topic.

These features seemed to be available in rosbag, which from my understanding is from ROS1. I have googled and searched this site a lot, but all answers seem to be related to rosbag. Is there a way to do this in ROS2, or can I use rosbag somehow with ROS2?

In rosbag there seemed to be both a `--filter` flag, and you could do `/topic:=/dummy/topic` to make the whole system ignore it.

The closest solution I have found is to, in the launch file run:

```
ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'bag', 'play', os.path.expanduser(
                #'~') + '/PATH/TO/BAGFILE/', '--loop', '--topics', 'TOPIC_1', ... ,'TOPIC_N']
```

But having a lot of topics already, this isn't really feasible with all the copy and paste that would be required, especially since I need to do this for multiple bag files with different topics on them.

Any way to solve this reasonably?

Using ROS2, Foxy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401287/can-i-filter-out-or-rename-topics-from-a-bag-file?/) by [i_](https://answers.ros.org/users/105902/i_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, remapping works with rosbags too:

```
ros2 bag play [bag name] --remap <old name>:=<new name>
```

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [i_](https://answers.ros.org/users/105902/i_/) on 2022-05-25**:
Ohh! I've been looking around, and I even checked the --help, and I *swear* I didn't see it before, and googling didn't give me a good answer, this does solve the specific problem at least neatly, at the cost of memory. Thanks, I even saw it in ros2 bag play --help

Do you know if it is possible to filter out topics? Basically the inverse of --topics ?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-25**:
`ros2 bag play -h` gives you the options.

I don't see a filter option, so my guess would be that it's not possible. However, it's important to note *why* you want to filter them out.

Did you record just too much and don't want it all clogging up your connection, in that case, I don't think there is an easy solution (you could hypothetically record a new bag while playing the old bag to filter it out that way, but that seems like a pain).

If you want to use (for example) your real camera data, and your bag also includes `/camera/image_raw` and that would mean you've got 2 publishers on that topic, you *could* simply do:

```
ros2 bag play [bag name] --remap camera/image_raw:=garbagetopic <another topic>:=<new name>
```

It's not the cleanest solution by a long shot, however it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [simple bash script](https://gist.github.com/tmxkn1/25a39d6cf4c66c38755c1c08c53efc1c) for excluding specific topics.

`--remap` is not good enough for me because the remapped topic will still consume resources. Currently, the only way is to use the `--topic` option to specify the topics to be included.

---

A quick explanation of the script is as follows.

We can use `ros2 bag info` to list all topics recorded in the bag. The script extracts and compiles the output into a string. Then, it searches for topics to be excluded and removes them from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we have '-x' or '--exclude' option for `ros2 bag play` command.

Which is a regular expressions to exclude topics from replay, separated by space.

Comment: This option is not available in humble